# Change Button value on click without id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's suppose my button is as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="BLUE" name="button_blue" />
```

What I want is when I click the button, `value="BLUE"` should be changed to `value="RED"` or anything I want.

Comment: Easy understandable solution if you want inline JS: `<input type="button" value="BLUE" name="button_blue" 
onclick="(this).value = 'red'"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the button has `name="button_blue"` attribute, use [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('[name=button_blue]').on('click',function(){
  $(this).val('RED');
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dw8kmh3g/

Answer (score 1):

Use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val) method:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $(this).val('RED');
});
```

To change it's previous value on click again:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $(this).val($(this).val() == 'RED' ? 'BLUE' : 'RED');
});
```

Comment: you really do not need jquery for this

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
  $(this).val($(this).val() == "RED" ? "BLUE" : "RED")
  //OR
  //this.value = this.value == "RED" ? "BLUE" : "RED";
});
```

Comment: i am doing this.. nothing is happening
`// #amenu7 is my button id.. 
$("#amenu7").on('click',function(){
  $(this).val($(this).val() == "+" ? "-" : "+")
  
});`

Comment: @MültïThìnkër probably you have not used right selector.. see demo code http://jsfiddle.net/edVaS/112/

Answer (score 0):

First add an id to the button -

```
<input type="button" id="myColorButton" value="BLUE" name="button_blue" />
```

Then add the following piece of code to your script -

```
document.getElementById("myColorButton").onclick = function() {
    this.value="RED";
};
```

Comment: You can just use `this` and do not need to get the element again in the function body

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a separate CSS class:

```
.button{
background-color:red;
}
```

And then add the class on click:

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){
!$(this).hasClass('ButtonClicked') ? addClass('button') : '';
});
```

You can also create the ability to have an "on/off" switch feel by toggling the class:

```
<button id="button">Hello</button>
```

here working link: [this jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edVaS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this completely without jQuery:

```
<input id='button' type="button" value="BLUE" name="button_blue" />
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
    this.value = 'red';
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jg1hjk1u/